# Proving $(\forall a,b \in \Bbb R)(a<b\implies(\exists r\in\mathbb Q)(a^7<r-4<b^7))$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

> Prove the following statement:
> $$(\forall a,b \in \Bbb R)(a<b\implies(\exists r\in\mathbb Q)(a^7<r-4<b^7))$$
> Hint: You may need to use the theorem: Given any two real numbers $a < b$, there is some $r \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $a < r < b$

I tried to use the theorem and looked forward on how to include the powers of 7, but not quite sure if I am right to apply my ideas this way: Define r = (a^7 + b^7)/2, which is the average of a^7 and b^7.
Since r is a real number, we can find a rational number q that is arbitrarily close to r.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Did you try to use the hint?

Comment: Yes, but I have not been able how to put the powers of 7 in the role.

Comment: @A.P. How about defining r as the A.M. of a^7 and b^7 ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion Blue. I tried to not mess it with my work, but will include it too :)

Comment: If $a<b$, then $a^7 < b^7$.

Comment: @peterwhy , can you send any resource with further information about this statement please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a < b$ and $7$ is odd, it follows that $a^7 < b^7$. Therefore, by the hint, take some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a^7 < q < b^7$. Define $r = q + 4$; then $a^7 < r - 4 < b^7$, and $r \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You should be able to see my deleted answer.  You may consider adding extra comments to show that $f(x)=x^7$ is a strictly increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a and b are arbitrary real numbers such that a < b. Our aim is to find a rational number r such that a^7 < r - 4 < b^7. Consider the function f(x) = x^7 - 4. This function is continuous on the interval [a, b], which means that it takes all values between f(a) and f(b). In particular, there exists some c in (a, b) such that f(c) = (a + b) / 2. Since c is in (a, b), we have a < c < b. Furthermore, since c is a root of the equation x^7 - 4 = (a + b) / 2, it follows that c is a solution to a polynomial equation with rational coefficients. By the algebraic closure of the real numbers, it follows that c is a real algebraic number. Thus, by the theorem of Liouville, it follows that c is a rational number. Therefore, we have found a rational number r = c such that a^7 < r - 4 < b^7, and the proof is complete.

Comment: What is the "polynomial equation with rational coefficients" to which "$c$ is a solution"? The constant term of $x^7-4 = (a+b)/2$ can be irrational, so this equation is probably not one.